# Can you tell why my Wordpress website display white page?

Tags: wordpress

I am new to Wordpress platform and I have just created a new website. When I thought I am done the website display a white page without any messages: https://nomad-provisions.com/
Is it possible to know the source of this problem?
Thank you

Comment: Without seeing the PHP behind it? It's pretty hard to tell. A blank white page generally indicates some sort of Wordpress error, but it's impossible to inspect because the HTML it spits out is completely empty.

Comment: To get you started, you'll need to [enable error messages](https://webdevstudios.com/2009/04/07/how-to-display-error-messages-in-wordpress/). This assumes that your web host has enabled an htaccess file for your site. There may be workarounds in this case, but I think it's site-specific.

You'll also want to disable these messages as soon as you've found the problem; you generally don't want your site spitting out debug data to public users.

Comment: PHP Error logs? Check with your host they should have something available to you to see what errors are in the log which will likely point to a specific line of code in a specific file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can try:

- Disable all of your plugins and check again. Caching plugins cause
  this issue.
- Contact your hosting provider and ensure that all caching is disabled
  on server.
- Connect to your server using FTP and re-name the /wp-content/plugins/
  folder temporarily to something else such as /wp-content/plugins-temp/. This
  will disable plugins for you.

If that fails you should enable the WP_DEBUG mode for WordPress. 
To do that open the file wp-config.php and add this to it:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

There should then be an error showing on the white screen. Take that error and show it to your hosting provider. Most often than not it is due to PHP memory which your hosting provider can increase.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the 'white' page shows that your plugins are making problems. The '**plugins**' folder is located in 'wp-content' folder.

I suggest you rename the '**plugins**' folder to '**plugins_backup**' in order to disable all the plugins
and see whether your site is back to normal or not. If your site was fine then create a new folder named '**plugins**' and copy your plugins one by one from '**plugins_backup**' folder to 'plugin' folder and you will find out which one is making your website white and gone.